# Creating hourly position vector from futures contracts in f#

Tags: c#, f#

I m trying to figure out when to use f# and when to use c#. I have a practical problem from energy trading. Power contracts are quoted as, Delivery start, Delivery End, Tarif, Volume. An example would be, 100MW Cal14 Offpeak, so from 1/1/14 to 31/12/14 the contract delivers 100MW each hour if the hour is between 20 and 8 (night hours) during the week or all hours on the weekend - total of ~5500 hrs. Peak contract delivers 8-20 on weekdays and Base delivers all hours in period.

If you have a portfolio of these contracts you want to aggregate them into an hourly position vector. Here my code so far:

Contract data example (with dates in Excel format):

```
let data = [(41275., 41639., "Base", 10.); (41275., 41639., "Base", 60.); (41275., 41639., "Peak", 20.); (41275.,41639.,"Offpeak",30.);  (41275.,41364.,"Peak",40.); (41275.,41364.,"Peak",70.); (41275.,41364.,"Offpeak", 50.)]
```

funciton that aggregates same contracts:

```
let group_fold keys value fold acc seq =
    seq |> Seq.groupBy keys 
        |> Seq.map (fun ((key1, key2, key3), seq) -> 
            (key1, key2, key3, seq |> Seq.map value |> Seq.fold fold acc))


let aggrTrades data =
data |> group_fold (fun (k1, k2, k3, _) -> k1, k2, k3) (fun (_, _, _, v) -> v) (+) 0.0
```

function that identifies peak and offpeak hours:

```
let poindicator dts =
    let newdts = DateTime.FromOADate dts
    // Match on day of week and hour properties of the date time
    match newdts.DayOfWeek, newdts.Hour with
    // For weekend, return false
    | DayOfWeek.Saturday, _ | DayOfWeek.Sunday, _ -> false
    // For working hours, return true
    | _, h when h >= 8 && h < 20 -> true
    // For non-working weekday hours, return false
    | _ -> false
```

Lastly a function that puts it all together and creates an hourly vector (std = start date of hourly vector and edd = end date):

```
let hourlyvec data std edd =
    let aggrdata = aggrTrades data
    let dtsvec = [std.. 1./24. .. edd]
    let nrhrs = dtsvec |> Seq.length
    let mutable res = Seq.init nrhrs (fun i -> 0.0)
    for i=0 to res |> Seq.length do
        for (a, b, c, d) in aggrdata do
            match a , b with
            | e, f when e <= dtsvec.[i] && f >= dtsvec.[i] -> 
                match c with
                | "Base" -> res.[i] <- res.[i] + d
                | "Peak" when poindicator (DateTime.FromOADate dtsvec.[i]) -> res.[i] <- res.[i] + d
                | "Offpeak" when not poindicator (DateTime.FromOADate dtsvec.[i]) -> res.[i] <- res.[i] + d
                | _ -> failwith "Not recognized tarif"
            |_ -> failwith "Not in period tarif"
    dtsvec, res
```

This fails with  FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Item' is not defined and also does not seem to like the nested poindicator function

Any pointers would be much appreciated? Also if you think this would be much easier in c# please let me know, I thought of it as a functional probelm so I went for f# first.

Comment: Suggestion for next time: This question contains a lot of unnecessary code.  Try to only show a minimal example that recreates the problem.

Comment: @JohnPalmer: This is a fine line though. I have done what you suggested previously and then people commented that it is not good to give not enough detail because sometimes your solution approach is wrong and then you only correct a mistake within the wrong approach

Comment: see here http://sscce.org/.  Some hints here - you could get rid of everything except the last code block and change `aggrdata` to be something like a sequence / array literal.  The `poindicator` function could just be something that returns `true` and you have cut about half the code without losing any meaning.

Comment: You could simplify this implementation quite a bit (which, in my experience, also tends to be a good way to get rid of bugs). If you post this code on the Code Review StackExchange, I'd be happy to help you improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is here

```
    match a , b with
    | e, f when e <= dtsvec.[i] && f >= dtsvec.[i] -> ...
```

If the condition is not met, you will get a match failure exception and the compiler correctly issues a warning.

This here will never work

```
        match _, _, c, _ with
        | "Base" -> res.[i] <- res.[i] + d
        | "Peak" when poindicator DateTime.FromOADate dtsvec.[i] -> res.[i] <- res.[i] + d
        | "Offpeak" when not poindic DateTime.FromOADate dtsvec.[i] -> res.[i] <- res.[i] + d
        | _ -> failwith "Not recognized tarif"
```

as you can only put the `_` in the part after the `|` not in the `match ... with`

Comment: thanks. got that fixed by adding a failwith on the first match. Why does res.[i] <- res.[i] + d this not work though? eror item not defined.

Comment: @nik - you can't use `a.[i]` syntax with sequences.  You probably want to use an array instead.

Comment: Great, didnt know that. How can I force let dtsvec = [std.. 1./24. .. edd] to be an array?

Comment: change it to `[|std.. 1./24. .. edd|]` (arrays use `[|......|]` for initialization and lists use `[.......]`

Comment: thanks John. I now have zero compiler errors in the version now updated in teh question, but it still doesnt run when used with the sample data posted above. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Please don't edit the question to remove the original problem.  You could just add the compiling code below the original code

Comment: @nik - I don't have time to debug that much code.  Come back with a simpler example

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping you'd re-post this question to the Code Review StackExchange, but since you didn't, I'll post my simplified version of your code here in case OP or future visitors find it useful:

```
let group_fold keys valueExtractor folder state seq =
    seq
    |> Seq.groupBy keys
    |> Seq.map (fun ((key1, key2, key3), seq) ->
        let finalState =
            (state, seq)
            ||> Seq.fold (fun state v ->
                let mappedValue = valueExtractor v
                folder state mappedValue)
        key1, key2, key3, finalState)

let poindicator dts =
    let newdts = DateTime.FromOADate dts

    // Match on day of week and hour properties of the date time
    // For weekend, return false
    newdts.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Saturday
    && newdts.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday
    // For working hours, return true
    // For non-working weekday hours, return false
    && newdts.Hour >= 8
    && newdts.Hour < 20

let aggrTrades data =
    data |> group_fold (fun (k1, k2, k3, _) -> k1, k2, k3) (fun (_, _, _, v) -> v) (+) 0.0

let hourlyvec data std edd =
    let dtsvec = [|std.. 1./24. .. edd|]

    let res =
        let nrhrs = Array.length dtsvec
        let aggrdata = aggrTrades data

        Array.init nrhrs <| fun i ->
            (0.0, aggrdata)
            ||> Seq.fold (fun periodValue (a, b, c, d) ->
                match a, b with
                | e, f when e <= dtsvec.[i] && f >= dtsvec.[i] -> 
                    match c with
                    | "Base" ->
                        periodValue + d
                    | "Peak" when poindicator dtsvec.[i] ->
                        periodValue + d
                    | "Offpeak" when not (poindicator dtsvec.[i]) ->
                        periodValue + d
                    | _ ->
                        failwith "Not in Tarif"
                |_ ->
                    failwith "Not in period")

    dtsvec, res
```